# How to add php file inside the confirm() function from JS

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

So, I want delete records from database using `confirm()` function, inside this alert should been shown what will be deleted when "OK" button will be clicked. To sum up, I just want to put php file inside the `confirm()`.

```
    function deleteGame() {
        if(confirm('Do you want delete this?')){
            $(".deleteButtton").load('deleteGame.php?id=' + $(".deleteButtton").data("id"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: You cannot, PHP only runs on the server your javascript is running in the browser

Comment: Look up the AJAX concept, thats what you will have to use

Comment: @RiggsFolly could you help me with AJAX solution?

Comment: Isn't the name somewhere in the DOM? Something like `$(".gamename").text()` will return the name, and you can put that in the prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm, I guess you must try AJAX Request for deleting record, check the following code for reference.

```sh
      if (confirm("Do you want this to be deleted?")){
          //HERE YOU CAN SHOW SOME PROGRESS WHILE THE JS IS REQUESTING PHP TO DELETE FILE
            $.get(
                "deleteGame.php",
                {
                  id: $(".deleteButtton").data("id")
                },
                function (result){
                 /*ASSUMING THAT YOUR PHP FILE WILL RETURN "deleted" AFTER DELETING RECORD.*/
                    if (result === "deleted"){
                         alert('DELETED!); //SOME ACTION AFTER DELETING.
                     }else{
                        alert('ERROR'); //SOME ACTION FOR ERROR
                     }
                }
           );
      }
```

I WOULD SUGGEST USING `POST` METHOD INSTEAD OF `GET` METHOD FOR SECURITY ISSUES.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to run a php function similar to deletion of a db record you have pretty much 2 options.

1. Open a new page in your browser or redirect a user to a new page.
2. Open a new page "silently" in a background without user knowing it.

The first option is ok, if you dont mind showing user a different page. For example if you wanted to show a page that would have text in it "Thank you for deleting this record". Achieving this would be really simple, you could just use javascript redirect like this:

```
if(confirm('Do you want delete this?')){
  window.location.href = 'deleteGame.php?id=' + $(".deleteButtton").data("id");
}
```

However in some cases you want to run the php function without leaving the current page. In cases like this you should use AJAX. My simplification: Using AJAX you can open the php file in the background, run the function and once its done you can run javascript to inform a user the operation was successful.
To achieve this you would need to add the AJAX call like this:

```
if(confirm('Do you want delete this?')){
        $.ajax({
          url: "deleteGame.php",
          method: "POST",
          data: { id: $(".deleteButtton").data("id")},
          success: function (result) {
            alert("The operation was successful")
          }
        });
}
```

And in your deleteGame.php file you would need to listen to incoming data:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
//Your own script to delete the record. You can access the record id by $id
```